# How to open a txt file and allocate its contents to a 2D array?

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, io

So I have a txt file that represents a matrix. what I need to do is open it up and allocate its contents to a Matrix.

For example:

in my txt file I have:

```
 39  -1 -42 -42 
 -6 -46  89  86 
 76 -62  35  92 
-20  24 -10  38 
 52   1 -86  41
```

I need to open up a file read its content and allocate each value respectively into a matrix.

I tried this, however, I still can not accesses a single element. I was thinking to use `strtok()` to break up the line into tokens as my backup plan but I am sure there should be a better way.

```
  int matrix[4][5];

  FILE *files;
  char str[100];


  files = fopen("./matrix-samples/m-5-10-a.txt", "r");
  if(files == NULL) {
    printf("%s\n","error" );
    }
  else{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      fgets (str, 60, files);
      printf("%s", str);
    }

  }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What code have you written? Have you opened the file using `fopen`? Have you read the first number using `fscanf`? Where did you run into problems?

Comment: @yano oops sorry typo

Comment: I have tried to use fopen and fgets. The problem occurred by trying to accesses a single value and then assigning it to a matrix position. @abelenky

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `strtok`.  The 9th circle of hell contains 3 functions: `gets`, `scanf`, and `strtok`.  Just avoid it.  Read the data with `fgets`, and parse it with something from the `strtol` family.  For example:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define ROW 5
#define COL 4


static void
die(int row, int col)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Invalid input in row %d, near column %d\n", row, col);
    exit(1);
}

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    const char *path = argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "matrix-samples/m-5-10-a.txt";
    int matrix[ROW][COL];
    FILE *ifp = fopen(path, "r");
    char str[256];
    if( ifp == NULL ){
        perror(path);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    int row = 0;
    while( row < ROW && fgets(str, sizeof str, ifp ) != NULL ){
        char *p = str;
        for( int col = 0; *p && col < COL; col += 1 ){
            char *end;
            matrix[row][col] = strtol(p, &end, 10);
            if( ! isspace(*end) ){
                die(row, end - str);
            }
            p = end + 1;
        }
        while( isspace(*p) ){
            p += 1;
        }
        if( *p || p[-1] != '\n' ){
            die(row, p - str);
        }
        row += 1;
    }
    if( fgetc(ifp) != EOF ){
        die(row, 0);
    }
    for( int i = 0; i < ROW; i++ ){
        for( int j = 0; j < COL; j++ ){
            printf("%7d", matrix[i][j]);
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }

    return 0;
}
```